# Pool.map() got stuck after running only first batch

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, multiprocessing, threadpool

I'm relatively new to python and very new to multithreading and multiprocessing. I've been trying to send out thousands of values (Approx. 70,000) into chunks through a web-based API and want it to return me data associated with all those values. The API can take on 50 values a batch at a time so for now as a test I have 100 values I'd like to send in 2 chunks of 50 values. Without multithreading, it would've taken me hours to finish the job so I've tried to use multithreading to improve performance.

**The Issue:** The code is getting stuck after performing only one task(first row, that even the header, not even the main values) on `pool.map()` part, I had to restart the notebook kernel. I've heard not to use multiprocessing on a notebook, so I've coded the whole thing on Spyder and ran it, but still the same. Code is below:

```
#create df data frame with
#some codes to get df of 100 values in 
#2 chunks, each chunk contains 50 values.

output:
df =                                                  VAL
0  1166835704;1352357565;544477351;159345951;22...
1  354236462063;54666246046;13452466248...

def get_val(df):
    data = []
    v_list = df
    s = requests.Session()
    url = 'https://website/'
    post_fields = {'format': 'json', 'data':v_list}
    r = s.post(url, data=post_fields)
    d = json.loads(r.text)
    sort = pd.json_normalize(d, ['Results'])
    return sort

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = ThreadPool(4)  # Make the Pool of workers
    results = pool.map(get_val, df) #Open the df in their own threads
    pool.close() #close the pool and wait for the work to finish 
    pool.join()
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check once with following

```
with ThreadPool(4) as pool:   
        results= pool.map(get_val, df)  #df should be iterable.
print(results)
```

Also, pls.check if chunksize can be passed to threadpool as that can affect performance.